# numeric textbox to display text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a numeric textbox in a table row where user enter some number and save the row. I would like to display some text added to this number while display. For example, if user enters 25 in textbox and save the row. The row item should look like "entered 25 today". I do have edit, save and options for each row. We will consider only the value in our back-end but for display purpose we need to show it as meaningful string.

```
<input type="number" min="1" name="edit_name_${adstatus.index}" id="edit_name_${adstatus.index}" class="form-control" value="<c:out value="${item.actionParameterDisplay}" />" />
```

Any way i can do this?

Comment: Try using :before and after in css, Another thing you can do is hide the textbox and show label on save button click

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery with some div having unique id of which content is changed after each change made in input having id "edit_name_" like 
`

```
$("[id^=edit_name_]").each(function () {
   $(this).on('change', function (e) { 
     //your code here to append or rewrite div content
    });
 });
```

`
Hope this will help.